# Find an html element

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have following HTML markup. I am required to get the index of li element w.r.t to its parent element when any of the li element is clicked.
Here is the HTML code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < allTags.length; i++) {
    allTags[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var x = event.target;
      var parent = x.parentElement;
      console.log("Parent " + parent.innerHTML);
      var count = 0;
      console.log("Parent text is " + parent.innerHTML);
      for (var child = parent.firstChild; child != null; child = child.nextSibling) {
        // console.log("X text  "+x.innerHTML);
        // console.log("Child Text "+child.innerHTML);

        if (child.isSameNode(x)) {
          alert("Index is " + count);
        }
        count++;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<!-- When <li> is clicked display alert which will contain index number of <li> and count of <li> in parent <ul> -->
<div class="holder">
  <ul class="list" id="lists">
    <li>1 text text text</li>
    <li id="item">2 text text text
      <ul id="lists1">
        <li>Ahtesham
          <ul> Samaid
            <li>1 text text text</li>
            <li>2 text text text
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li>text text text</li>
          <li>text text text</li>
          <li>text text text</li>
          <li>text text text</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>text text text</li>
      <li>
        text text text
        <ul>
          <li>text text text</li>
          <li>text text text</li>
          <li>text text text</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>text text text</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="lists2">
    <li>text text text</li>
    <li>text text text</li>
    <li>
      text text text
      <ul>
        <li>text text text</li>
        <li>text text text</li>
        <li>text text text</li>
        <li>text text text</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The code does give me an index but it does not correspond to the actual index of the clicked element in the HTML.

Comment: Please expand on what `w.r.t` means exactly and what expected results would be

Comment: @charlietfl `w.r.t.` means `with respect to`

Comment: @VicJordan I assume that but still doesn't explain expected results and is open to interpretation

Comment: w.r.t means element's index relative to its parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you've got one major and one minor problem here.

The major problem, which is resulting in an incorrect index, is that there are a lot of things that could be a part of the parents child list that aren't things you would consider to be "nodes", such as whitespace and the like.

To remedy this, switch `parent.firstChild` to `parent.firstElementChild` and `child.nextSibling` to `child.nextElementSibling`. That, for the most part will fix the code, but just a fix to minor problem, you also probably want to call `event.stopPropagation` at the top of you listener, or else it will recursively call the same logic on all parents up the dom hierarchy, resulting in multiple alerts that probably aren't expected.

Correct code:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
var allTags=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0;i<allTags.length;i++){
    allTags[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var x=event.target;
        event.stopPropagation(); \\ prevent unnecessary alerts
        var parent=x.parentElement;
        var count=0;
        for(var child=parent.firstElementChild;child!=null;child=child.nextElementSibling){  
            if(child.isSameNode(x)){
                alert("Index is "+count);
                return; // went ahead and returned from the listener function here, since you've found what you want
            }
            count++;
        }
    });
}
  };
```

Cheers!

Comment: When I comment the event.stopPropagation() call, the event starts to bubble downward even if I pass false as thirds to addEventListener. Why won't the event propagate up?

Comment: Downward and upward are somewhat relatively terms when you're referring to Dom hierarchy. By default, all JavaScript events start at the deepest node and propagate to their parents, all the way to the root node, unless stop propagation is called. So, in this example, we're calling stop propagation so that an alert will only display for the exact <li> that was selected.

I was assuming that was the behavior you wanted, but maybe I misunderstood. Are you wanting something different? What behavior is happening right now that isn't correct?